# how to generate html page using html editor content and save in root folders

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

in my requirement i entered HTML content using HTML editor then **i want to  save that entered**  content in directory folders with extension of .HTML. i am using this **wysiwyg** editor in asp.net. please help me to solve this solution thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your html is being correctly saved inside the .html files?

> You should check if the html is correctly being passed on from wysiwyg to your .html file.

**UPDATE**

you can generate a new file using ASP like this -

```
protected void generateHtmlFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("pathToServerRoot/file.html"), true))
 {
  file.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text); // Write the file.
 }         
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no i want to generate new html page with my html content

Comment: so you should send the generated html to your asp.net backend first and then create a file with the generated html and save it on your root...?

Comment: ok. how to generate new html file.

Comment: @chaitanya check my updated answer, don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem, thanks.

Comment: sure how to take html content into this file. please help i am new to this

Comment: you have to post a form to the ASP.net backend... read this --> http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_inputforms.asp

Comment: thanks for help its works